# SQL: Dynamic view with column names based on column values in source table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Given the two sample tables here:

**Tickets Table**

```
ID  User    Description

0   James   This is a support ticket
1   Fred    This is a ticket too
```

**Properties Table**

```
ID  TicketID    Label           Value

0   0           Engineer        Scott
1   1           Engineer        Dale
2   0           Manu            Dell
3   1           Manu            HP
4   0           OS              Windows
5   1           OS              Linux
```

How can I arrive at a view like this:

```
ID  User    Description                 Engineer    Manu    OS

1   James   This is a support ticket    Scott       Dell    Windows
2   Fred    This is a ticket too        Dale        HP      Linux
```

It is important to note that the properties table would not always be the same.  Some "Tickets" may have properties that others do not.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Property tables are the devil.

Comment: @Jeremy so can hard-coding property names as column names. Both have their place.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, once again I don't disagree with you... but every time I have to use property tables I almost always have performance issues, and they are usually a pain in the butt to pivot.

Comment: @Jeremy but that does not necessarily represent every time *for everyone* - I've used EAV with great success in the past, I even blogged about it because so many people have this blanket opinion that it's such a terrible thing. https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/11/19/what-is-so-bad-about-eav-anyway.aspx  It's like cursors. Are they bad in general? Yes. Are they always bad? Absolutely not.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can perform this with a [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). When doing the PIVOT you can do it one of two ways, with a Static Pivot that you will code the rows to transform or a Dynamic Pivot which will create the list of columns at run-time:

Static Pivot (See [SQL Fiddle for Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cfd92/1)):

```
select id, [user], [engineer], [manu], [OS]
from 
(
    select t.id
        , t.[user]
        , p.ticketid
        , p.label
        , p.value
    from tickets t
    inner join properties p
        on t.id = p.ticketid
) x
pivot
(
    min(value)
    for label in ([engineer], [manu], [OS])
) p
```

Or you can use a Dynamic Pivot (See [SQL Fiddle for Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cfd92/7)):

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(p.label) 
                    from tickets t
                    inner join properties p
                        on t.id = p.ticketid
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT id, [user], ' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                 select t.id
                        , t.[user]
                        , p.ticketid
                        , p.label
                        , p.value
                    from tickets t
                    inner join properties p
                        on t.id = p.ticketid
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                min(value)
                for label in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

Both query will return the same results.

Comment: your first example is considerably more complicated than mine with the exact same results, and the second one... dynamic sql?  Before going that route, I think you'd want to make darn sure that's a requirement and how the table is going to be consumed.

Comment: You are my new hero.  I want to have your babies. (Dynamic Pivot works EXACTLY how I need)

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs I disagree that the first is more complicated than your version with 3 left joins.  As far as the dynamic version, the OP requested a dynamic version of a query which would be flexible and that is what I provided. There are always other ways to answer a question, feel free to suggest another dynamic way. :)

Comment: This is very slick. We'd love to have you post on [DBA.SE](http://dba.stackexchange.com/). (As a side note, you can remove the `TYPE` and `.value()` from the XML query. The call to `.value()` is unnecessary without the `TYPE`.)

Comment: But you can't use dynamic sql in a view, can you?