# Transact-SQL in BO XI?

Tags: business-objects, infoview

I recently asked the following question and received a wonderful answer: [SQL: Dynamic view with column names based on column values in source table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10986031/sql-dynamic-view-with-column-names-based-on-column-values-in-source-table)

As someone not familiar at all with BusinessObjects, is there any way to perform this in InfoView?  Would I have to edit the universe?

Sorry, I know this is a terrible question... but we're in a bind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be possible via a derived table in the universe.  A derived table allows you to write a custom query to provide objects in the universe.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's the path we're taking.  Initially I didn't have access to the universe... we'll see.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. It would require the dynamic creation and destruction of objects.